# What is the programmatic approach in Qt's MVC to get widgets with a structurally different view on the same data?

Tags: python, qt, model-view-controller, pyqt

I just learned about the model/view concept in Qt and arrived at a rather general question.

I understood how Models can be used to associate certain **data types** to appropriate Widgets, for example `QAbstractListModel` can associate a list to a `QListView` or a `QComboBox`.

Special benefit arises, when multiple widgets are associated to the same data via a common model, such as a `QComboBox` and several `QListView`s communicating to the same, single `QAbstractListModel`.

I noticed, that in the textbook demonstrations this situation is always chosen such that the widgets display the data in the **same structure**, e.g. the entries of the Combo and the List at position `i` are both derived from the `i`eth list item, rather than from the total content of the data.

My question is, generally, how would one approach the situation where **the same data is to be displayed by different widgets in completely different structures**, i.e. the entries (and their number) is a general function of the whole dataset?

To give a (rather complex) example, say that my *data* is a list of lists of integers,

```
my_list = [[1,2,3], [2,3,4,5]]
```

and I would like to display it using two widgets as follows:

```
QTableView

List      | Length | First Item
----------+--------+-----------
[1,2,3]   | 3      | 1
[2,3,4,5] | 4      | 2


QTreeView

+ [1,2,3]
   + Length
      + 3
   + First item
      + 1
   + Left-truncated Sublists
      + [2,3]
         + Length
            + 2
         + First item
            + 2
         + Left-truncated Sublists
            + [3]
               + This list very nice because it contains no 2
               + Length
                  + 1
               + First item
                  + 3
      + [3]
         + This list very nice because it contains no 2
         + Length
            + 1
         + First item
            + 3
+ [2,3,4,5]
   + Length
      + 4
   + First item
      + 2
   + Left-truncated Sublists
      + [3,4,5]
         + This list very nice because it contains no 2
         + Length
            + 3
         + First item
            + 3
         + Left-truncated Sublists
            + [4,5]
               + This list very nice because it contains no 2
               + Length
                  + 2
               + First item
                  + 4
               + Left-truncated Sublists
                  [5]
                   + This list very nice because it contains no 2
                   + Length
                      + 1
                   + First item
                      + 5
            + [5]
               + This list very nice because it contains no 2
               + Length
                  + 1
               + First item
                  + 5
      + [4,5]
         + This list very nice because it contains no 2
         + Length
            + 2
         + First item
            + 4
         + Left-truncated Sublists
            + [5]
               + This list very nice because it contains no 2
               + Length
                  + 1
               + First item
                  + 5
      + [5]
         + This list very nice because it contains no 2
         + Length
            + 1
         + First item
            + 5
+ there are 2 lists in total
```

Of course I do not expect a fully coded detailled answer, but some hints or resources would be nice, how to approach this using the MVC in `Qt`/`PyQt`.

Comment: you could explain in detail the structure that is shown in the QTreeView. 
Do you want the following? https://imgur.com/a/m8g9RMM

Comment: @eyllanesc Not exactly, every `+` refers to a node, the indentation gives the hierarchy. However, note that my question is not on the implementation details of this particular problem. I am asking how two widgets would *principally* derive two *structurally different* representations from the same data model.

Comment: Actually the model is the data itself, but the relationship between the elements, for example: `my_list = [[1,2,3], [2,3,4,5]]`, is not a model because it does not There is a relationship. If you want to have more details about the structure of the models in Qt, I recommend reading http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html. Each type of view expects a type of model, so look for the other items with respect to the model or structure they have defined

Answer (score 0):

That's what viewmodels are well suited for. They are proxy models: they adapt the source model for a certain organization of display. You'd be usually deriving from `QAbstractProxyModel`. A simple example is provided e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21569029/1329652).